# Springer GTM Series statement of purpose (early editions)

Tags: soft-question, books

Earlier editions of the Springer Graduate Texts in Mathematics series include a motivating statement about the purpose of the series.  The [current statement](https://www.springer.com/series/136) of purpose is as follows:

> Graduate Texts in Mathematics bridge the gap between passive study and
> creative understanding, offering graduate-level introductions to
> advanced topics in mathematics. The volumes are carefully written as
> teaching aids and highlight characteristic features of the theory.
> Although these books are frequently used as textbooks in graduate
> courses, they are also suitable for individual study.

I believe the earlier statement of purpose, from the paper books, is somewhat more colorful.  Does someone have access to an early GTM book to check?  I believe the statement is found just inside the cover; it isn't present in digitized versions that I've seen online.

Answer (score 9):

Aha, found it, via a footnote to my own PhD thesis :-)

> “A student approaching mathematical research is often discouraged by the sheer volume of the literature
> and the long history of the subject, even when the actual problems are readily understandable. Graduate Texts
> in Mathematics, is intended to bridge the gap between passive study and creative understanding; it offers introductions on a suitably advanced level to areas of current research. These introductions are neither complete
> surveys, nor brief accounts of the latest results only. They are textbooks carefully designed as teaching aids;
> the purpose of the authors is, in every case, to highlight the characteristic features of the theory. Graduate
> Texts in Mathematics can serve as the basis for advanced courses. They can either be the main or subsidiary
> sources for seminars, and they can be used for private study. Their guiding principle is to convince the student
> that mathematics is a living science.”

You can also find a copy of the text in the linked backmatter of [Advanced Mathematical Analysis](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4684-9886-8) (1973), GTM #12, as digitized on SpringerLink. Looking around, some early versions of the text have as the second sentence "The new series, Graduate Texts in Mathematics...". Presumably the author was Paul Halmos?